# How to add a space in the middle of a word

Tags: java

Hey guys having trouble adding a space in between a word. what i need to do is convert English to Vogon which i have done but you also have to add spaces at ever 5 character any ideas how to do that here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    translateFromEnglish("hello");
    }
    public static boolean detect(String phrase) {
        return false;
    }
    public static String translateFromEnglish(String phrase){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        phrase = scan.nextLine();
        String NewString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'a') {
                NewString += "n";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'b') {
                NewString += "o";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'c') {
                NewString += "p";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'd') {
                NewString += "q";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'e') {
                NewString += "r";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'f') {
                NewString += "s";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'g') {
                NewString += "t";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'h') {
                NewString += "u";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'i') {
                NewString += "v";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'j') {
                NewString += "w";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'k') {
                NewString += "x";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'l') {
                NewString += "y";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'm') {
                NewString += "z";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'n') {
                NewString += "a";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'o') {
                NewString += "b";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'p') {
                NewString += "c";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'q') {
                NewString += "d";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'r') {
                NewString += "e";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 's') {
                NewString += "f";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 't') {
                NewString += "g";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                NewString += "h";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'v') {
                NewString += "i";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'w') {
                NewString += "j";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'x') {
                NewString += "k";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'y') {
                NewString += "l";
            }
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == 'z') {
                NewString += "m";
            }




        }
        System.out.println(NewString);
        return phrase;

            }
```

Console
hello how are you doing // user input
uryybubjnerlbhqbvat  // new phrase

Comment: You may want to consider using a `switch` statement instead of those repeated `if`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a counter and increment it in the for loop. At the end of all if statements put

```
count++;
if(count % 5 == 0){
    NewString += " ";
}
```

Comment: Also it's better to make newString a StringBuilder to not recreate the whole string object on every character append.

Answer (score 1):

Using StringBuilder is more efficient because you don't need to create a string each time:

```
    String translatedString = "aaaaabbbbbeeeeecccccdddddfffffgggg";
    int numOfChars = 5;
    StringBuilder vogon = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < (translatedString.length() / numOfChars); i++) {
        vogon.append(translatedString.substring(i * numOfChars, (i * numOfChars) + 5)).append(" ");
    }

    // append any remaining characters
    vogon.append(" ").append(translatedString.substring(translatedString.length()/numOfChars));

    System.out.println(vogon);
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the fifth character and add a string, inside your `for` loop, you can include something simple like this:

```
if (i % 5 == 0){
    newString += " ";
}
```

Comment: Ah, my code won't work because you named your string `NewString`. Convention does suggest the use of lowerCamelCase to name objects.

Comment: that was funny Panda i was about to ask you about the count thanks for the help.

Comment: Now do i put that in each if or right after each if? Do you many instead of having NewString just have newstring

Comment: this would work as long as there was only one word but when i try a phrase it is counting the spaces that is already in it and then adding 1 after so it is only giving me 4 char and not 5.

Comment: never mind i just had to change 5 to 6 because of how java counts. one more question through how would i have the program detect vogon since it is the same either way it is detected